# Nuget Libray in Unity for other platform

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine

I have a project that used Nuget Libraries and I implemented in Unity using C#. The program worked if I run Unity in Windows, but I wonder is it possible to port this project to another platform using Nuget library inside the code? because Nuget Library is a library for .NET in Windows. I actually want to implement this Nuget Library to LuminOS which can run the application from unity.

If I use Nuget Library in Unity? Is it possible to deploy the games on another platform besides Windows for example for Android, iOS, or LuminOS? Is it gonna work because Nuget package is libraries we use for Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi i have the same problem except i want to build for android and i have searched for an answer this is what i got:
you should reach to .dll files and put them in package folder and this is the only way it will work on android here is an example: 
https://answers.unity.com/questions/743400/database-sqlite-setup-for-unity.html

I managed to make it work some thing you should keep in mind is i think the only way to make it happen is by set your player build settings -> other settings -> scripting Backend to Mono and Api Compatibility Level to .Net standard 2.0

Comment: Thanks for your answer, at least I could hope that It would worked

Comment: I tried onnxruntime to load onnx model in unity, it works fine on unity windows but when I deployed to magic leap, it doesn't work so I tried another method using Barracuda to load onnx model and it worked but Barracuda is developed by unity